# using private key in yml file to connect to snowflake

Tags: jdbc, parameters, yaml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, private-key

I have received username and private key in az keyvault to connect to snowflake. I m not provided with password.
We are using liquibase for github ci/cd. In the yml file, I need to establish connection to snowflake using jdbc.

```
--url=jdbc:snowflake://${{ACCOUNT}}.snowflakecomputing.com:XXX/?warehouse=${{WAREHOUSE}}&db=${{DATABASE}}&schema=${{SCHEMA}}....
```

What connection parameter should I be using to connect to snowflake using private key. Everywhere its mentioned to use

```
--private-key-path rsa_key.p8
```

how to create the file and use it

```
use --ssh_key parameter
```

it dint work

Comment: Creating public/private keys up is covered in the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth

Answer (score 0):

Example connection string from [Private Key File Name and Password in Connection String](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/jdbc/jdbc-configure#private-key-file-name-and-password-in-connection-string)

```
jdbc:snowflake://myorganization-myaccount.snowflake.com/?private_key_file=/tmp/rsa_key.p8&private_key_file_pwd=dummyPassword
```